# Bootstrap CSS file cannot be loaded into chrome locally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

When I am running this HTML code on Chrome and Firefox ,the bootstrap file(LOCAL) is not loaded .But when I run it in IE it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
Name of the file is nav.html.
Output is same as it was earlier.

This is the of the project[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU1jj.png)
This is how  [BootStrap Css folder structure looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZeno.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `href` value with a relative path.

If these are the paths in your project:

- `I:/Projects/Angular/learning/nav.html`
- `I:/Projects/Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Then this is the href value you need in your link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Please post your revised markup and some information about the structure of your project. Which folder contains the HTML code in your question?

Comment: Have uploaded folder structure pictures.OUTPUT is SAME as earlier.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your project's directory structure.